# Need to seperate green-blue region from white region in image

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I am working on detection of dental issues using thermography. I need to seperate the green-blue region from the white region, which is the region of interest.

[image]

Comment: can you please provide expected result?

Comment: the expected result is having an image showing only the white region, eliminating the blue-green edges completely

Answer (score 0):

there are many thresholding methods you can use. here I used HSV color space:

```
rgb = imread('dental.png');
hsv = rgb2hsv(rgb);
mask = hsv(:,:,3) > 0.8 & hsv(:,:,2) < 0.2;
imshow(mask)
```

[image]

Comment: _this works well . however cal you tell me how did you determine the values used in_ mask = hsv(:,:,3) > 0.8 & hsv(:,:,2) < 0.2;